# Belongs to through method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How do I do a sort of `belongsToThrough` to get the currency of a plan via an intermediate country table?

This is my db structure:

```
plan
    id - integer
    country_id - string // country.code

country
    code - string
    currency_id - string // currency.code

currency
    code - string
```

I need a `currency()` relationship in the Plan model:

I've tried a few times to no avail. I thought something like this but this just returns null:

```
class Plan extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function currency()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(
            Currency::class, // $related,
            'currency_id', // $foreignKey = null,
            'code', // $ownerKey = null,
            'country' // $relation = null
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need two `BelongsTo` relationships:

```
class Plan extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'country_id', 'code');
    }
}

class Country extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function currency()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class, 'currency_id', 'code');
    }
}

$currency = $plan->country->currency;
```

If you want to get the currency in one step:

```
class Plan extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function getCurrencyAttribute()
    {
        return $this->country->currency;
    }
}

$currency = $plan->currency;
```

Comment: But this will generate 2 separate database queries right? Is there a way to do it through 1?

Comment: @DanielCheung Yes, it does. In Laravel 5.8+, you can use a [`HasOneThrough` relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) by switching the foreign and local keys. Before that: https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through

Answer (score 0):

In My Case I have

> **ShopOwner** ->(hasmany) **Shops** ->(hasmany) **Employees**

Now i want to fetch all `Employees` of a `ShopOwner`. which means Employee list filtered by ShopOwner.

My Employees Model:

```php
<?php

namespace Modules\ShopOwner\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employees extends Model
{
    public function shop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\Modules\ShopOwner\Entities\Shops', 'shop_id');
    }

    public function scopeByShopowner($query, $shopownerId)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('shop', function ($query_shop) use ($shopownerId) {
            $query_shop->where('shopowner_id', $shopownerId);
        });
    }
}
```

So now i can fetch it using:

```php
Modules\ShopOwner\EntitiesEmployees::byShopowner($shopownerId)->get();
```